# Mine to remote address with monerod

Tags: monerod, mining, cpu-mining, solo-mining

I started the mining process with:

`start_mining <walletaddress> 16`  and,

`start_mining 16 <walletaddress>`

Both returned: `Error: invalid argument: must be either 0/1, true/false, y/n, yes/no`

How do I mine on one machine, but automatically send the reward to an address on another machine.

Answer (score 1):

In the daemon (`monerod`):

```
help start_mining 
Command usage: 
  start_mining <addr> [<threads>|auto] [do_background_mining] [ignore_battery]

Command description: 
  Start mining for specified address. Defaults to 1 thread and no background mining. 
  Use "auto" to autodetect optimal number of threads.
```

The wallet address (`<addr>`) can be any wallet's main (not sub) address. It doesn't matter where the wallet is (local or remote).